# C - strcpy pointer

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy

I want to ask about strcpy. I got problem here. Here is my code:

```
char *string1 = "Sentence 1";
char *string2 = "A";

strcpy(string1, string2);
```

I think there is no problem in my code there. The address of the first character in string1 and string2 are sent to the function `strcpy`. There should be no problem in this code, right?
Anybody please help me solve this problem or explain to me..

Thank you.

Comment: Can't change string literals http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/strlitnomod.html

Comment: String literals (your `"Sentence 1"` and `"A"`) are unmodifiable (under penalty of Undefined Behaviour) char arrays. You cannot (reliably) `strcpy()` into such an array.

Comment: Is it okay if I will use char * string1; only? then I will use string copy twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem -- your pointers are each pointing to memory which you cannot write to; they're pointing to constants which the compiler builds into your application.

You need to allocate space in writable memory (the stack via `char string1[<size>];` for example, or the heap via `char *string1 = malloc(<size>);`). Be sure to replace  with the amount of buffer space you need, and add an extra byte at least for NULL termination. If you `malloc()`, be sure you `free()` later!

Comment: Thanks!! That explains why `char string2[50]` works. I am newbie in pointer, so a little confused how to use pointer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This gives undefined behaviour. The compiler may allow it, due to a quirk of history (string literals aren't `const`), but you're basically trying to overwrite data which on many platforms you simply cannot modify.

Answer (score 0):

From linux man pages:

> char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
>   The  strcpy()  function  copies the string pointed to by src,
>   including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer  pointed  to
>   by  dest. The  strings  may  not overlap, and the destination string
>   dest must be large enough to receive the copy.

You have a problem with your *dest pointer, since it's pointing to a string literal instead of allocated, modifiable memory. Try defining string one  as `char string1[BUFFER_LENGTH];` or allocate it dynamically with `malloc()`.